# "Choose an account" form does not disappear when clicking cancel

Tags: java, android, dialog, google-plus, google-play-services

When the app is running for the first time. I ask the user to login to their Google Plus account. However, if the user clicks off the dialogue or clicks cancel. The dialogue to "Choose an account" will reappear continually. How do I change it so that the dialogue will only appear once, if cancelled, it will not show again.

This code is stored in my OnCreate:

```
    if(VariableStore.loggedIn == false){
    mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
    .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
    .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
    .addApi(Plus.API)
    .addScope(Plus.SCOPE_PLUS_PROFILE)
    .build();
    }
```

Comment: Did you find any solution ?

Answer (score 0):

I create API client like this:

```
mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
    .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
    .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
    .addApi(Plus.API)
    .addScope(Plus.SCOPE_PLUS_LOGIN)
    .setAccountName(myAccountName)
    .build();
```

The difference is in **SCOPE_PLUS_LOGIN** - hope it helps. But in my case (since Google Play services v7.0), it's also important to **setAccountName** explicitly. Otherwise, we get the similar issue.